# Want to know how can I separate these express routes into their own files

Tags: express, routes, refactoring, passport.js

Want to know how can I separate these express routes into their own files. I have tried this a couple of ways and I'm starting to feel like I'm guessing. I do not want to guess I want to have a solid understanding of how express is routing passport through with the routes.

```
//const loginRoute = require('./modelroutes/')
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

// normal routes ===============================================================

    // show the home page (will also have our login links)
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('../public/views/index.ejs');
    });

    // PROFILE SECTION =========================
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('../public/views/profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });

    // LOGOUT ==============================
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

// =============================================================================
// AUTHENTICATE (FIRST LOGIN) ==================================================
// =============================================================================

    // locally --------------------------------
        // LOGIN ===============================
        // show the login form
        app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
            res.render('../public/views/login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the login form
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

        // SIGNUP =================================
        // show the signup form
        app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
            res.render('../public/views/signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the signup form
        app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

    // facebook -------------------------------

        // send to facebook to do the authentication
        app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

        // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
        app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
            passport.authenticate('facebook', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));

    // twitter --------------------------------

        // send to twitter to do the authentication
        app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', { scope : 'email' }));

        // handle the callback after twitter has authenticated the user
        app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
            passport.authenticate('twitter', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));


    // google ---------------------------------

        // send to google to do the authentication
        app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

        // the callback after google has authenticated the user
        app.get('/auth/google/callback',
            passport.authenticate('google', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));

// =============================================================================
// AUTHORIZE (ALREADY LOGGED IN / CONNECTING OTHER SOCIAL ACCOUNT) =============
// =============================================================================

    // locally --------------------------------
        app.get('/connect/local', function(req, res) {
            res.render('../public/views/connect-local.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });
        app.post('/connect/local', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/connect/local', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

    // facebook -------------------------------

        // send to facebook to do the authentication
        app.get('/connect/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

        // handle the callback after facebook has authorized the user
        app.get('/connect/facebook/callback',
            passport.authorize('facebook', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));

    // twitter --------------------------------

        // send to twitter to do the authentication
        app.get('/connect/twitter', passport.authorize('twitter', { scope : 'email' }));

        // handle the callback after twitter has authorized the user
        app.get('/connect/twitter/callback',
            passport.authorize('twitter', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));


    // google ---------------------------------

        // send to google to do the authentication
        app.get('/connect/google', passport.authorize('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

        // the callback after google has authorized the user
        app.get('/connect/google/callback',
            passport.authorize('google', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
            }));

// =============================================================================
// UNLINK ACCOUNTS =============================================================
// =============================================================================
// used to unlink accounts. for social accounts, just remove the token
// for local account, remove email and password
// user account will stay active in case they want to reconnect in the future

    // local -----------------------------------
    app.get('/unlink/local', function(req, res) {
        var user            = req.user;
        user.local.email    = undefined;
        user.local.password = undefined;
        user.save(function(err) {
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });

    // facebook -------------------------------
    app.get('/unlink/facebook', function(req, res) {
        var user            = req.user;
        user.facebook.token = undefined;
        user.save(function(err) {
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });

    // twitter --------------------------------
    app.get('/unlink/twitter', function(req, res) {
        var user           = req.user;
        user.twitter.token = undefined;
        user.save(function(err) {
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });

    // google ---------------------------------
    app.get('/unlink/google', function(req, res) {
        var user          = req.user;
        user.google.token = undefined;
        user.save(function(err) {
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });


};

// route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

If any one can help explain to me how express is routing passport within the routes through separate directories.

Answer (score 0):

A route in Express is handled through a series of middleware functions from left to right. So, `passport.authenticate()` and `passport.authorize()` simply return a suitable middleware function which does its business logic and takes care of redirecting.

If you want to distribute your routes over multiple files (say one for Google, one for Facebook, one for local signup) one thing you can do is something like this:

```
/* 
 * google.js.
 */

// return a function which given passport returns a function 
// which will actually install the relevant routes on a Express app
//
// the reason for the indirection is that 
// you might end up wanting to inject other middleware
// so keeping the deps separate makes it easier/safer 
// for callers to assume a uniform interface.
const installMyGoogleMiddleWare = passport => app => {
};

module.exports = installMyGoogleMiddleWare;
```

Then use it like this:

```
/*
 * app.js
 */
const passport = ...
const app = ...

const allRoutes = [
    require('google.js'), 
    require('facebook.js') /* ... */
].map(factory => factory(passport));

allRoutes.forEach(route => route(app));
```